# Group by column as a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data tables with data something like this:

```
Data         category
------------------------
apple        fruits
spinach      vegetables
mango        fruits
lion         animals
grapes       fruits
tiger        animals
potato       vegetables
```

and I want a query to display the data as follows:

```
vegetables
spinach
potato 
fruits   
mango               
grapes
animals
lion       
tiger
```

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want? I do not see the relation between data and category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to design schema properly ,I think it may helps you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.category') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE category

CREATE TABLE category (
    categoryID INT Identity PRIMARY KEY
    ,categoryName VARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT  INTO category(categoryName)
SELECT 'fruits'    Union all 
SELECT 'vegetables'Union all
SELECT 'animals'

SELECT * from category


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Datacategory') IS NOT NULL
Drop Table Datacategory

CREATE TABLE Datacategory (
    DatacategoryID INT Identity
    ,categoryID INT CONSTRAINT FK_Datacategory_category FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES category(categoryID)
    ,Data VARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT INTO Datacategory(Data,categoryID)
SELECT     'apple'    ,1  Union all
SELECT     'spinach'  ,2  Union all
SELECT     'mango'    ,1  Union all
SELECT     'lion'     ,3  Union all
SELECT     'grapes'   ,1  Union all
SELECT     'tiger'    ,3  Union all
SELECT     'potato'   ,2
```

Query to get desired result

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(CASE 
                    WHEN RNo = 1
                        THEN categoryID
                    ELSE ''
                    END, '') AS VARCHAR), '') AS categoryID
    ,Data
FROM (
    SELECT D.categoryID
        ,D.Data
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY D.categoryID ORDER BY D.categoryID
            ) AS Rno
    FROM Datacategory d
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.categoryID = d.categoryID
    ) Dt
ORDER BY Dt.categoryID
```

OUTPUT

```
categoryID  Data
----------------
1           apple
            mango
            grapes
2           potato
            spinach
3           lion
            tiger
```